# Is it possible to play a sound from android alarm manager's callback in the background?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dart-isolates

I am trying to create a basic alarm app which plays a sound at the given time. For this, I am using the [android_alarm_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager) plugin. To play the sound, I am using the [flutter_ringtone_player](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ringtone_player) plugin

```dart
main(List<String> args) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      ...
        home: HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      ...
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.alarm),
        onPressed: () async {
          await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShotAt(
            DateTime.now().add(Duration(seconds: 5)),
            10,
            _fireAlarm,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

void _fireAlarm() {
  FlutterRingtonePlayer.play(
    android: AndroidSounds.notification,
    ios: IosSounds.glass,
    looping: true, // Android only - API >= 28
    volume: 0.1, // Android only - API >= 28
    asAlarm: false, // Android only - all APIs
  );

  print('Alarm fired!');
}
```

The application runs as intended when it is in foreground. However, when the `floatingActionButton` is tapped and the app is closed, the app crashes in the background.[image: Application crash screenshot]

I am using flutter version 2.0.6 and the API version of the emulator is 29, which I believe comes with Flutter Android Embedding V2 which means no additional configuration is required according to the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager#flutter-android-embedding-v2) (at the bottom).

I have tried looking at resources on the web but I did not have much luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It will shut down, it suppose to shut down. Flutter has what we call isolates. It is basically running the alarm process in another memory that will not depend on the main activity memory. Google workmanager, isolates for background task..